# jquery\grails form submit not working in IE

Tags: jquery, grails, spring-webflow

I'm trying to use a submitToRemote button for webflow in my grails application.  I'm using jquery to handle the ajax.  I've created a custom taglib which alters the submitToRemote button to be within a web flow and attache the eventId as such...

```
def remoteWebFlowSubmit = {attrs, body ->

        def elementName = attrs['name'].replaceAll(/ /, "_")
        def button = submitToRemote(attrs, body) //<-- standard grails submitToRemote button

        button = button.replaceFirst(/data\:jQuery/, "data:\'_eventId_${elementName}=1&\'+jQuery")

        out << button
    }
```

**This works in Fire Fox and Chrome** but does not submit any form data in IE 9,8, or 7.  The generated button looks like this in IE:

```
<input name="next" onclick="showSpinner('webFlowContainer');;jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:'_eventId_next=1&'+jQuery(this).parents('form:first').serialize(), url:'/MySite/MyController/run?execution=e3s1',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#webFlowContainer').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){jQuery('#webFlowContainer').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);}});return false" type="button" value="Next"/>
```

What am i doing wrong?  I see no errors in the JS console.

**UPDATE:**

1.) I've also added a grails filter to prevent the ajax response from being cached.  Here is the filter:

```
class AjaxFilters {
    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                if (request.getHeader('X-Requested-With')?.equals('XMLHttpRequest')) {
                    response.setHeader('Expires', '-1')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any JS errors?  What if you put logging in the `error` block of your `ajax` call, rather than leaving it blank?

Comment: I've updated my question and added the error block.  no js errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that I'm calling the `onclick="showSpinner('webFlowContainer');` on the same div that contains the form elements I'm trying to submit.  If I use a different div to display a ajax spinner it works fine.

Thanks!